# Openshift - how to redirect to custom domain

Tags: dns, openshift

1. I have an app hosted on OpenShift. OpenShift generated me a URL: example.lol-rhcloud.com.
2. I own custom domain: "myname.pl" which i bought on nazwa.pl (polish company).
3. I would like to redirect myname.pl to the app hosted on OpenShift.

My domain provider tells me I need to give them name of server DNS's(at least two of them). But sorry, I can not find this on OpenShift.

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift has instructions for this on their [help site](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202301854-How-can-I-set-up-my-own-domain-name-to-point-to-my-app-).

1. Use the rhc client tools to run > rhc alias add {appName} {alias}
2. Then in your DNS management for www.yourDomain.com you can add a cname to point www.yourDomain.com to appName-namespace.rhcloud.com.

Comment: The link is broken.