# How to link custom domain from GoDaddy to Openshift version 3?

Tags: dns, openshift

I have been working with Openshift 2 and I added CNAME record for the same in GoDaddy. There was a way to add an alias in Openshift 2. Now when I am migrating to Openshift 3 with Openshift 2, I am not able to find any resource to do this.

What steps need to be followed to complete this migration?

Comment: @NickZinger saw your response to same question for Openshift version 3 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454943/openshift-how-to-redirect-to-custom-domain). Could you please suggest on how to do here.

Comment: Are you using OpenShift Online Starter or Pro? Custom domains aren't supported in Starter, only in Pro. Search for 'openshift route custom host' here in SO and are a number if questions about this. There is also documentation at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/routes.html#creating-routes Look at those and if you are having a specific problem with getting it to work then indicate what it is and can help.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: In two of your prior posts I have removed requests for urgency, and now I discover deadlines in your latest question. What can I say to ask you to desist from hurrying volunteers? It really is not appropriate.

Comment: @halfer I do not understand the problem with mentioning deadlines which are totally accurate. The Openshift team is asking to migrate the application to version 3 before Sept 30. Is it wrong to mention that and in this case it is actually urgent?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks for quick response. I am using OpenShift Online Starter. In previous version of Openshift it was supported, so I thought of using the same here. I will look into the "Routes" and progress. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it really is wrong to ask volunteers to do anything urgently, in any case whatsoever. If you need genuinely urgent help, you need to find and pay a contractor, so they can work to the timescales you need. Please read the entirety of the link I have supplied, so you can understand the community's view on this matter.